# HDD Partitionning on a live system under Debian and ext3

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, partition, ext3

I have my server running under Debian using ext3. All the whole root is into a single main partition on a single hard drive.

I would like to create a second ext3 partition on the same hard drive.

So is there a way to resize a live partition and create a new one without loosing data?

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called `resize2fs` that will let you resize an ext3 partition, but not while it is mounted. Most likely you'll have to shut off the machine and boot if off external media.

Comment: To be more specific, you can't shrink a mounted partition.  Under a specific set of conditions, a partition can be enlarged while mounted.

Comment: Which boot cd offers a graphical interface for partitionning?

Comment: http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page.  Once it is booted follow the onscreen directions to start gparted.